# subset dictionairy and flatten output to list

Tags: python

I have a dictionairy

```
d = {0: ['LON', 'SFO', 'LIS'], 1: ['MAD', 'LAX', 'ROM'], 2: ['BOS', 'SAO', 'SLC']}
```

That I want to subset for all the keys that are 0 or 1.

I tried:

```
[v for k, v in  d.items() if k in [0, 1]]
```

But this returns

```
[['LON', 'SFO', 'LIS'], ['MAD', 'LAX', 'ROM']]
```

Is there anything I could add to the subset line that would return a flat list?

Comment: Maybe just `d[0] + d[1]`?

Answer (score 2):

You could change your list comprehension to something like:

```
[item for k,v in d.items() if k in [0,1] for item in v]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is almost never a reason too look at all keys in a dictionary when you want to take a subset of the values. So any variation of:

```
[v for k, v in  d.items() if k in [0, 1]]
```

is less than ideal because you need to look at all the items in the dict. Given a set of keys you are interested in, you should iterate over the keys and only look at those items in the dict.

Something like this avoids looping through the whole dict (and then looping through a list of keys to test):

```
from itertools import chain

d = {0: ['LON', 'SFO', 'LIS'], 1: ['MAD', 'LAX', 'ROM'], 2: ['BOS', 'SAO', 'SLC']}
keys = [0, 1]

list(chain.from_iterable(d.get(k, []) for k in keys))
# ['LON', 'SFO', 'LIS', 'MAD', 'LAX', 'ROM']
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
[dest for k in keys for dest in d.get(k, [])]
```

Using `d.get(k, [])` allows `keys` to contain non-valid keys without raising an exception, which may not be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I could add to the subset line that would return a flat list?

So you just want to flatten your list?

```
flatten_list = [element for k, v in  d.items() if k in [0, 1] for element in v]
```

Comment: Did you test this before posting it? You get an error because you are calling `sum()` when the values are strings.

Comment: I forgot to delete sum() after editing the list comprehension, thank you